# What does $g_0$ mean for a centrifuge?

Tags: literature, experimental-design

I'm about to make some Graphene Oxide and in the paper for Tour's Method it uses a centrifuge to isolate the solution. However it requires $319g_0$. What does this mean, and will a centrifuge with 3300rpm suffice?

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234084399_Graphene_oxide_for_effective_radionuclide_removal

Answer (score 1):

$g_0$ is the **[standard gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravity)**.

You can look up the rpm-equivalent using a [nomogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomogram) or [calculate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifuge#Mathematical_description) it yourself.

On some centrifuges you can switch between both. Some vendors provide conversion tables in their centrifuge's manual.